# Unity DI, design-time configuration in layered application

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

We have been using Unity container for dependency injection without any problems for a couple of years. Simplified we have three layers Web/Domain/Data.

We use design-time configuration to be able to switch some implementations for different builds.

IMyDataInterface is registered from web.config. Data-layer resolves IMyDataInterface successfully. When trying to resolve IMyDataInterface from Domain-layer it fails with the following message.

> InvalidOperationException - The current type, IMyDataInterface, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Each layer has a UnityConfig-class that registers the dependencies.

```
Web creates IUnityContainer instance A
   Calls Web.UnityConfig.RegisterTypes(A)
     Registers design-time types from web.config by running A.LoadConfiguration() 
       (web.config contains registration of IMyDataInterface)
     Registers types from Web-layer
     Calls Domain.UnityConfig.RegisterTypes(A)
       Registers types from Domain-layer
       Calls Data.UnityConfig.RegisterTypes(A)
           Registers types from Data-layer
```

```cs
public class MyDataClass
{
    public MyDataClass(IMyDataInterface dependency)
    {
        // dependency is resolved
    }
}

public class MyDomainClass
{
    public MyDomainClass(IMyDataInterface dependency)
    {
        // dependency FAILS to resolve
    }
}
```

If I register type IMyDataInterface in Data.UnityConfig, everything works but I need to be able to switch implementation at design-time using web.config.

Comment: Without actual code, there isn't much we can do to help. Are you creating any child containers ever? Are you overriding / removing previous registrations somewhere? Did you break into the registration processes of both the web.config and the data.unityconfig? During the resolution, have you looked at the list of registrations to see if something is odd?

Comment: I has somehow configured IMyDataInterface as a named dependency in web.config. Removing the name resolved everything. I found the error when I was about to copy the code here. Thanks you @Tipx